# When I speak into the Android phone, where does the data go?

Tags: android

When I use the option to speak into my Android phone to search or something, I notice it reaches out to some server or something, then comes back and works and shows me the text of what I said. I am curious where is this connecting to? A google server or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some insight in to how speech works in android,

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html